# Displaying different data in tabs based on a variable

Tags: javascript, php

I am creating a view for users to easily switch between data they want to see. 
The scenario: User is a manager of a group with a number of stores with different franchises. Our dashboard allows him to view collated results for all the stores. At the moment, the user has a separate login for each franchise. I want to be able to show both in one login by using tabs.

I have created two buttones

```
<button class="tab tablinks active" onclick="openCity(event, 'table_products')">Franchise 1 </button>
<button class="tab tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'products_location')">Franchise 2</button>
```

And then 2 divs with corresponding IDs

```
<div id="table_products" class="tabcontent" width="100%" >
<?
    include 'load_table.php';
?>
</div>

<div id="products_location" class="tabcontent" style="display: block" width="100%" >
<?
    include ('load_table.php');
?>
</div>
```

I also have javascript to switch the CSS styles of style display. I am struggling with passing the variable to the correct file in order to know which franchise data to display.

I have tried

```
include ('load_table.php?franchise=a');
```

but that didn't work, since PHP looks for that exact file name. I have also tried

```
include 'https://www.example.io/platformDev2/load_table.php?franchise=a';
```

but that is throwing up an error as well, saying that file doesn't exist. Is there another way in which I can achieve what I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A PHP include, load the file content in running script.

For example:

Given two files, a.php and b.php

```
a.php

echo "Hi";
echo "I'll load now other file";
include "b.php";
echo "now I've returned";

b.php

echo "Now I'm on file b";
```

The result will be when you call a.php:

```
Hi
I'll load now other file
Now I'm on file b
now I've returned
```

For doing what you're trying, the best option is to have a function inside load_table.php

Example:

```
load_table.php

function load_info ($franchise) {
  if ($franchise = 1) {
    echo "Hi";
  } else {
    echo "bye";
  }
}
```

And the main code will be:

```
<?php include ('load_table.php'); ?>
<div id="table_products" class="tabcontent" width="100%" >
<?php
    load_info(1);
?>
</div>

<div id="products_location" class="tabcontent" style="display: block" width="100%" >
<?php
    load_info(2);
?>
</div>
```

(Note I'll only include the file one time, and call the function two times).

Comment: Oh I like this a lot! I will give it a try and see if it does what I need it to do! Thank you.

Comment: So I tried implementing that code and now whenever I try to switch between the tabs, I get the following error `master_admin.php:649 Uncaught ReferenceError: openCity is not defined` which is the function to change CSS and it does exist. Any idea what could be causing that?

Comment: That's unrelated to the first question, because openCity function is a js one. If it's failing now, then before also will be failing. Update your question with full code for viewing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

include basically makes the code of the included file become part of the main script - as if it had been written there in the first place.

So the included code has access to all variables the exact same way any code directly written in that place would have.

So you can easily do

```
<?
    $somevar = 'somevalue';
    include 'load_table.php';
?>
```

and then access `$somevar` inside of `load_table.php` …

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use global variables like that :

view.php :

```
<div id="table_products" class="tabcontent" width="100%">
<?php
    $selection = "a";
    echo include "load_table.php";
?>
</div>
<div id="products_location" class="tabcontent" style="display: block" width="100%">
<?php
    $selection = "b";
    echo include "load_table.php";
?>
</div>
```

load_table.php :

```
<?php

global $selection;

switch ($selection) {
    case "a" : return "Table #1";
    case "b" : return "Table #2";
}
```

Comment: This doesn’t need `global $selection;`, the variable will be available in load_table.php without it.

Comment: of course, just for seeing where come from of $selection variable.

Comment: No clue what you mean by that. The `global` keyword has a very specific meaning and functionality. You sound like you are confusing it with what should be an annotation or a comment.